# Firebase Lab test "Unable to instantiate activity" on some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am tested my android app on firebase lab test.
And my app pass 6 devices and and fail on 8 devices I am found in debug report this error for most of failures : Unable to instantiate activity.
Why it's runing on 6 devices and fail on this 9 devices ?

Here is the tests that faild :

1- Robo test, Galaxy Note 3 Duos, API Level 19:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

---

2- Robo test, Xperia Z3, API Level 21 :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID:
>   12050 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0.

---

3- Robo test, HTC One (M8), API Level 19

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID:
>   16853 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

---

4- Robo test, Nexus 7 (2012), Virtual, API Level 19:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID: 5004 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
>   /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

---

5- Robo test, Nexus 10, Virtual, API Level 21 :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID:
>   12050 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0.

---

6- Robo test, Nexus 10, Virtual, API Level 19 :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID:
>   6656 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
>   /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

---

7- Robo test, Galaxy S4 mini, API Level 19:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID: 9465 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

---

8- Robo test, Nexus 4, Virtual, API Level 19:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie, PID:
>   4902 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie.SplashScreen" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.apk4android.salluu3alayhie-1, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

---

Comment: what is the api level of the devices that it worked on?

Comment: @PeterHaddad those the devices :
Nexus 6P, Virtual, API Level 26
Portrait
—
Huawei Mate 9, API Level 24
Portrait
—
Nexus 6, Virtual, API Level 25
Portrait
—
Nexus 5X, Virtual, API Level 26
Portrait
—
Nexus 9, Virtual, API Level 25
Portrait
—
Low-resolution MDPI phone, Virtual, API Level 26
Portrait
—

Comment: then you having something in your code that is not supported in those lower api I think

Comment: @PeterHaddad Is compile SDK affect ? I am using API Level 25

Comment: no its something in the code in that specific activity/xml.. is the activity declared in manifest?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes of course  its declared.

Comment: please show the activity and xml

Comment: Regarding the API 21 `IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0` error, the discussion at this question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605877/illegalargumentexception-radius-must-be-0